# What are the strings outside the baseball bat called?

Tags: image-identification

So I found a cartoon;

[image: cartoon]

There are some strings coming out from the end of the bat. What are they called?

Comment: Baseball bats don’t usually have tassles but that’s what they are.  This might be a baton.

Comment: That looks like an old-fashioned policemans night-stick. The thongs are sometimes called lanyards.

Comment: From the direction he's looking in, Uncle Sam seems particularly concerned about interference from New Zealand.

Comment: Baseball wouldn't have been popular enough for its bats to be recognizable in Monroe's time.

Comment: It is not a baseball bat. It's a policeman's stick, baton, truncheon, or 'billy club'.

Answer (score 12):

The "bat" looks like an old-fashioned policeman's night stick--here remimiscent of the famous "big stick" of Rooseveltian (first one) foreign policy, or possibly a reference to America as "the world's policeman". The thong through the handle could be termed:

[Lanyard](https://www.google.com/search?q=lanyard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

> a cord passed around the neck, shoulder, or wrist for holding a knife, whistle, or similar object.

although they are usually a closed loop. It might also be called a ***[tassel](https://www.google.com/search?q=tassel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_8hyWJ7JO8_R8AfE04D4Dw)***,

> a tuft of loosely hanging threads, cords, or other material knotted at one end and attached for decoration to home furnishings, clothing, or other items.

if it is only for decoration.

EDIT

A reverse image look-up on Google located the image and tied it to the [**Roosevelt Corollary to the Monroe Doctrine**](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv-9XPqjXZ91gZsSzpA_1oLNoahPDCJLzmZ4ot7j5tZDx_1aQnPBrE0GNvASEN9ejfRGIGteVG_1RXF_1_1ef8s85m5Yt9w45h8JmD97xNTul0t6kboc8aljWQfeijAlumtaaT5hGuvl1YVMVnb_1EtZX9ncA72rf8KYitBeGbRiC9YeqA7uoVvMMgLzmvsWZSJOtRGbNyw4EtffsbOxscmKHIQ01SdyPpnHbq2eZaAcJ0il5YlhnHMNzzumvyTFPucw4mnGy2SOvkezpVFxqftWrKtZc2FZZ0GTBQCDqoGPk79peudf2en_1oh3Ezt2wUYMCJA5kDEX3n5Wg0Sr9pzMBr64jxUL1fvBkgx42M6hE_1qv9xzXPgnFDtfeFEJEwuJHW9NNiNE7UHMapm88h4fJMsat5ba6gJXXIUPyYRR4WO-1wQ0YrPOyFerpJcdW_1astycmuzA55YAITpTIXn5Mm9CLKLK0KGQeURvH6Shp8REHCc4Pp7jrqTzi7veC1VnRX6XhaG01Vii02eygy7qm32TWP-2WtUZXXQg23UjMHcrJOvmlK2tp7qCstjVK9TrZ7pF2lDOVmrz0C7OTpP2G9qxl9IzeEVUuWwZ5L6s4jOVg3tLtfUaTftUdo4nuch9bC7_177X_11I5-FOjMmLDXRAXI5fY10zdLRBjAx77kBexvuk4AdqbLxmc8ZLdsmsbhDW3YeK7WBMSkFhtsjhXv8VsDpU94fS9etUw4Hafr7r-96Ud-qyAgTRzWfgx3VrSQoSEKM3gmSQ5-DpRffP8Oh3biFM84BS7VvhKTJ_1oHXUNVAOFHcQQTmtev-Un8KuULqRW2MNBRHr9n9KwYVVNrQ0vHHnxyDMOXAPr1F-nFfGsQz0zClFLPMADIEpsF7usQpGhtUDD-I8ciQOdTe18qUgFx8mJ0C3GefNU2E7pEgjDHwLpLkSHRrtmOVxyAMKA6O-XA1vac8WQOBGynKMx7ldo5yvuvUsAdyKXhFc3VCxQ1pfDwU-hR7skLWFQUx445VUmuC_1zzqdI12G88IhAqH_1ZxK7mCdc05K3fPBSt8qySQKSjScsEtw54rqNdzPWNNi_11kbWL6cf64qqQELuRSbOSHnDn9r590uxItWjSggl2L5jNW7B6gvSDIj6posw3QjhLCm9knuuV8-A95KgMhkugHXDl9ZL-HWaI3HtmmJymTczdYxp8cf0EV843iT-N82KTeW4PhWqYBY860WcmfC5UAp6KyDcF-PL2-psfxfGZAhtUmD5BSehc5UZxmUHjkukeoS8G3FIij_1cKog2WKtIpYd1_1-cM9IiKDrFvdKwpkFMBSXYAe9TRz85LaIrGvpjtpsUeSA0NKlOG8cLHyxBE7SgcH3NWNqRasWf0YhkpyqB8H6c8P9ppXLBFcqDo3j1BSjOljqZB7RthEfwO9XuHpNJfV9bjff6vKNFlxIxryVC7rZ-TFKtF8tUE0RQLlbcTpfR7CP9cdFJyi_19EXmWddsO9o3hglgRcBE4JQ28VW9tk-d7frjWqvnZV84Aj1uiDWx8-vBrkgU3v0jNhSzLfZ6102to1DweOmtHGHEGR4I4hBLhDKK2Ga5WOwPmtuDf4zezPGrvcAhol7C1L53gxHhb6HDIUlzjwckNUZ-3GGt1NjpHhJenXsDZMJL2zqHsh9LilkheHMdckHAPslgxym85bhhf0vOgVGjNZi78oNSceePOa4oNakXiGwvBAV1A5TlwVnugeHcVlH3QUzRWhnjHIdAHO39ssd1gFYz3_189YBPOiNVg6ja71lR4u0W2B0fvqcHiOxGB&hl=en).

Comment: *the famous "big stick" of Rooseveltian foreign policy* You're off by about 90 years.

Comment: I don't know when the cartoon was published, but the Monroe Doctrine was declared in 1823.

Comment: @deadrat ["The intent and impact of the Monroe Doctrine persisted with only minor variations for more than a century."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_Doctrine) "Before becoming president, Theodore Roosevelt had proclaimed the rationale of the Monroe Doctrine in supporting intervention in the Spanish colony of Cuba in 1898"

Comment: The US has expended the Monroe Doctrine to include the entire world. That  still won't rescue a reference to TR here from anachronism.

Comment: @deadrat After thinking about your comments, I edited in that it might refer to America "as the worlds policeman. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: The date on the club is hard to read, but I think it says 1814-1898. I'm not sure why 1814. Monroe didn't become President until 1817, although he was Secretary of War and Secretary of State under Madison. But I think it's no coincidence that the time span starts with the beginning of the demise of the Spanish Empire in the western hemisphere and ends with its effective death from the Spanish-American War. That war started the US on its imperial path, but the country didn't become a global, meddling power until later. I like your answer enough to upvote it.

Comment: @deadrat Thank you for your comments: it prompted a change in the post.  Did you notice my edit? I definitely tied it to Roosevelt with a reverse image look-up.

Comment: Good catch here: https://www.quia.com/jg/1532420list.html Same club; same lanyard. But if I'm reading the dates correctly, TR can't be involved in the message of the cartoon.

Comment: @deadrat The dates look to me like 1824 to 190-something, but not sure....

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you where they came from

> The sword knot or sword strap, sometimes called a tassel, is a lanyard—usually of leather but sometimes of woven gold or silver bullion, or more often metallic lace—looped around the hand to prevent the sword being lost if it is dropped. Although they have a practical function, sword knots often had a decorative design. For example, the British Army generally adopted a white leather strap with a large acorn knot made out of gold wire for infantry officers at the end of the 19th century; such acorn forms of tassels were said to be 'boxed', which was the way of securing the fringe of the tassel along its bottom line such that the strands could not separate and become entangled or lost. Many sword knots were also made of silk with a fine, ornamental alloy gold or silver metal wire woven into it in a specified pattern.
>
> The art and history of tassels are known by its French name,
>   passementerie, or Posamenten as it was called in German. The military
>   output of the artisans called passementiers (ornamental braid, lace,
>   cord, or trimmings makers) is evident in catalogs of various military
>   uniform and regalia makers of centuries past. The broader art form of
>   passementerie, with its divisions of Decor, Clergy and Nobility,
>   Upholstery, Coaches and Livery, and Military, is covered in a few
>   books on that subject, none of which are in English.
>
> Indian swords had the tassel attached through an eyelet at the end of
>   the pommel.
>
> Chinese swords, both jian and dao, often have lanyards or tassels
>   attached. As with Western sword knots, these serve both decorative and
>   practical functions, and the manipulation of the tassel is a part of
>   some jian performances.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilt

BTW, searches using "club", "thong" and "tassel" were certainly interesting, but didn't produce any hard evidence ;)

Comment: +1 very interesting discussion. You might note that the [Webley Mk-VI .455 was issued with a toggle for attaching a lanyard](https://www.google.com/search?q=webley+mk+vi+lanyard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=tdRzWL6wGcew8weerJKIBg), which was extremely useful in the trenches during WWI.